# I need to make a website in which software should I start

Tags: html, web

I need to make a website more or less like this one 
--> http://www.anestesiologiachp.com/index.php#
What software should I use and where should I begin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is clearly off-topic.

Comment: You should ask this somewhere else. Anyway, I would recommend you using Wordpress. It's a software easy to use. Juste search a theme that looks like this website. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the designing part using bootstraps, it would be easier using the 12 grid system. You just need a text editor like notepad(notepad++ or sublime text would better) and a web browser for rendering the html pages.

Answer (score -1):

I think after investing some time to understand HTML,CSS AND JAVASCRIPT,and after you learn how to work with an WYSIWYG EDITOR(FOR EX. adobe dreamweaver),you can finish you site really easy! :)Good luck!!

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: So ...a starting point with learning html,css and javascript is't essential in your opinion?So..may I ask you....how you have started to buid websites?